# How to fetch all documents from one of the collection of Azure's Cosmos DB using JAVA?

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-cosmosdb, endpoint

I gone through the documentation , there are two ways to fetch the documents

1. using Azure's Endpoint 
   https://{databaseaccount}.documents.azure.com/dbs/{db-id}/colls/{coll-id}/docs 
   even i set the required headers Token and all I am getting some exception

> {
>            "code": "Forbidden",
>            "message": "Sql api is not supported for this database account\r\nActivityId: fc5ec296-b7a1- 
>             44df-9c69-42e804177242, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.7.0"
>           }

2. using SDK
   through the sdk also i m getting the same above exception , below is the java code which i m using 
   for fetching the documents

   ```
   public class App {
   private static final String END_POINT = "https://***.documents.azure.com/";
   private static final String MASTER_KEY = "***";

   // Define an id for your database and collection
   private static final String DATABASE_ID = "iotdata";
   private static final String COLLECTION_ID = "details";

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       DocumentClient documentClient = new DocumentClient(END_POINT, MASTER_KEY, new ConnectionPolicy(),
               ConsistencyLevel.Session);
       System.out.println("Check if database " + DATABASE_ID + " exists.");
       String databaseLink = String.format("/dbs/%s", DATABASE_ID);
       try {
           ResourceResponse<Database> readDatabase = documentClient.readDatabase(databaseLink, null);
           if (readDatabase.getStatusCode() == 200) {
               System.out.println("Connection Established");

           }

           FeedResponse<Document> queryResults = documentClient.queryDocuments("/dbs/iotdata/colls/details",
                   "SELECT * FROM details WHERE mac_address = '28:b2:bd:01:d0:94'", null);

           System.out.println("Running SQL query...");
           for (Document family : queryResults.getQueryIterable()) {
               System.out.println(String.format("\tRead %s", family));
           }

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Please don't mention your private key or real info in your question which is maybe dangerous. Already edited for you, still suggest you to re-generate them!

Comment: that's not my primary key, that key was already edited. Thankx

Comment: ok,that's fine.So,your cosmos db account is sql api or mongo api?It seems you try to access mongo db account by using sql api way.

Comment: but through the endpoint also i m getting the same exception, there is no need to write the query for the API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/list-documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,i have to say that your sample code in second point is totally right.I tested it and works with Cosmos DB Sql Api.

[image]

According to the error:

> Sql api is not supported for this database account

It seems that you want to access cosmos db account of other type(maybe mongo api i guess) with [SQL API REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/list-documents) or SQL API SDK. That's forbidden and i'm afraid that's the reason for above error.If your Cosmos DB account is using the Mongo API, you should be using tools and drivers that use the Mongo API. Please refer to this case:[Sql api is not supported for this database Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58126046/sql-api-is-not-supported-for-this-database-error)